# Trying to use $compileProvider, CRUD and bootstraped directive ng-clink failed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, symfony

I have a trouble with simple application, like this exemple:

**ng-click after compile does not work.**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-compile-production</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="compileExample">
  <script>
    angular.module('compileExample', [], function($compileProvider) {
        // configure new 'compile' directive by passing a directive
        // factory function. The factory function injects the '$compile'
        $compileProvider.directive('compile', function($compile) {
          // directive factory creates a link function
          return function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(
              function(scope) {
                // watch the 'compile' expression for changes
                return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
              },
              function(value) {
                // when the 'compile' expression changes
                // assign it into the current DOM
                element.html(value);

                // compile the new DOM and link it to the current
                // scope.
                // NOTE: we only compile .childNodes so that
                // we don't get into infinite loop compiling ourselves
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
              }
            );
          };
        });
      })
      .controller('GreeterController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.name = 'Visitor';
        $scope.html = 'Hello {{name}} have a look at <form><button ng-click="popFailed()">ng click which Failed</button></form> After successful request';

        $scope.popSuccess = function() {
          alert('pop success');
        };

        $scope.popFailed = function() {
          alert('test success');
        };
      }]);
  </script>
  <div ng-controller="GreeterController">
    <form>
      <button ng-click="popSuccess()">ng click which succed</button>
    </form>

    <br/>
    <input ng-model="name"> <br/>
    <textarea ng-model="html"></textarea> <br/><br/><br/><br>
    <div compile="html"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- Exemple of angularJs bootstrapping
        <script>
            // bootstrap the app to angular
            angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('compile_example'), ['compile_example']);
        </script>
    -->
</body>
</html>
```

But when Im using symfony which provide rest-api that generate my template (like $scope.html), return string of html as describe in the example. but My ng-click does not work. EventListener e.g. (ev) indication does not apear on my browser inspector

I am using angular.bootstrap with id instead of ng-app for my application declaration

I need help

- I thought that it is due of my angular.bootstrap position on the bottom page
- Event e.g. (ev) indication is shown on browser inspector for this example but does not apear on my project
- How to know if html and directives has been "compiled" properly? make event listener apear on my button form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was solved there :

[FOSRestBundle "avoid" Javascript eventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45231186/fosrestbundle-avoid-javascript-eventlistener/45234107#45234107)

I have make a mistake within my form template