# FOSRestBundle "avoid" Javascript eventListener

Tags: angularjs, rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

I am trying to create a simple CRUD application by using Symfony and AngularJs, My problem is as describe here:

[Trying to use $compileProvider, CRUD and bootstraped directive ng-clink failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45214521/trying-to-use-compileprovider-crud-and-bootstraped-directive-ng-clink-failed)

When I m trying to load my template (the whole forms without compile) by using :

```
{{ render(controler('App:getTemplate',{parameters})) }}
```

when I try whithout rendering it work well and I need to change my template dynamically.

My event listener does not apear over my angularJs diverctives, may this problem apear with FOSRestBundle which may avoid javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistaque was in my form declaration

symfony with angular form layout as default theme, like that :

error :

```
ng-model='data['{{ full_name }}']'
```

soluce ;

```
ng-model='data["{{ full_name }}"]'
```

That was stressful